# How to change order of payment method depend of user language in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

Firstly, sorry for my language. I want to modify my Prestashop 1.6. From back office I can change order of order of payment method (ex. check or bank wire). But I need something more. What I want to do is to change order of payment method depend on user language. For example. If user use English language then I want to display Paypal as first method. But in another the Paypal will be the second method.

I don't want code from You. Just tell me how can I do this ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible easily.

You can use a module that will do it for you but I don't know if such a module exists or activate multishop and use one shop by language and set the order by shop.